# Edit traccar elements via html file

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, traccar

I am using [traccar](https://github.com/traccar/traccar) open source GPS tracking system, and I want to edit some html elements but I cant because it is made it in exitjs and and I dont have a local files for editing but I saw that some developer using traccar file release.html to add html elements in that html file, how is that possible what do I need to change that I can use release.html for editing html elements for traccar?

traccar release.html file:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<title>GPS Lokator</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="spinner"></div>
<div id="attribution">Powered by <a href="https://gpslokator/">GPS Lokator sistem za pracenje lokacije</a></div>
<script id="loadScript" src="load.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

traccar load.js file:

```
    var debugMode, touchMode, locale, localeParameter, extjsVersion, proj4jsVersion, olVersion, i, language, languages, languageDefault;

    function addStyleFile(file) {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
        link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
        link.setAttribute('href', file);
        document.head.appendChild(link);
    }

    function addScriptFile(file) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('src', file);
        script.async = false;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }

    function addSvgFile(file, id) {
        var svg = document.createElement('object');
        svg.setAttribute('id', id);
        svg.setAttribute('data', file);
        svg.setAttribute('type', 'image/svg+xml');
        svg.setAttribute('style', 'visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:-100px;');
        document.body.appendChild(svg);
    }

    debugMode = document.getElementById('loadScript').getAttribute('mode') === 'debug';
    touchMode = 'ontouchstart' in window || navigator.maxTouchPoints;

    window.updateNotificationToken = function (token) {
        Traccar.app.updateNotificationToken(token);
    };

    locale = {};
    window.Locale = locale;

    locale.languages = {
        'ar': { name: 'العربية', code: 'en' },
        'az': { name: 'Azərbaycanca', code: 'en' },
        'bg': { name: 'Български', code: 'bg' },
        'bn': { name: 'বাংলা', code: 'en' },
        'cs': { name: 'Čeština', code: 'cs' },
        'de': { name: 'Deutsch', code: 'de' },
        'da': { name: 'Dansk', code: 'da' },
        'el': { name: 'Ελληνικά', code: 'el' },
        'en': { name: 'English', code: 'en' },
        'es': { name: 'Español', code: 'es' },
        'fa': { name: 'فارسی', code: 'fa' },
        'fi': { name: 'Suomi', code: 'fi' },
        'fr': { name: 'Français', code: 'fr' },
        'he': { name: 'עברית', code: 'he' },
        'hi': { name: 'हिन्दी', code: 'en' },
        'hr': { name: 'Hrvatski', code: 'hr' },
        'hu': { name: 'Magyar', code: 'hu' },
        'id': { name: 'Bahasa Indonesia', code: 'id' },
        'it': { name: 'Italiano', code: 'it' },
        'ja': { name: '日本語', code: 'ja' },
        'ka': { name: 'ქართული', code: 'en' },
        'kk': { name: 'Қазақша', code: 'en' },
        'ko': { name: '한국어', code: 'ko' },
        'km': { name: 'ភាសាខ្មែរ', code: 'en' },
        'lo': { name: 'ລາວ', code: 'en' },
        'lt': { name: 'Lietuvių', code: 'lt' },
        'lv': { name: 'Latviešu', code: 'lv' },
        'ml': { name: 'മലയാളം', code: 'en' },
        'ms': { name: 'بهاس ملايو', code: 'en' },
        'nb': { name: 'Norsk bokmål', code: 'no_NB' },
        'ne': { name: 'नेपाली', code: 'en' },
        'nl': { name: 'Nederlands', code: 'nl' },
        'nn': { name: 'Norsk nynorsk', code: 'no_NN' },
        'pl': { name: 'Polski', code: 'pl' },
        'pt': { name: 'Português', code: 'pt' },
        'pt_BR': { name: 'Português (Brasil)', code: 'pt_BR' },
        'ro': { name: 'Română', code: 'ro' },
        'ru': { name: 'Русский', code: 'ru' },
        'si': { name: 'සිංහල', code: 'en' },
        'sk': { name: 'Slovenčina', code: 'sk' },
        'sl': { name: 'Slovenščina', code: 'sl' },
        'sq': { name: 'Shqipëria', code: 'en' },
        'sr': { name: 'Srpski', code: 'sr' },
        'sv': { name: 'Svenska', code: 'sv' },
        'ta': { name: 'தமிழ்', code: 'en' },
        'th': { name: 'ไทย', code: 'th' },
        'tr': { name: 'Türkçe', code: 'tr' },
        'uk': { name: 'Українська', code: 'ukr' },
        'uz': { name: 'Oʻzbekcha', code: 'en' },
        'vi': { name: 'Tiếng Việt', code: 'en' },
        'zh': { name: '中文', code: 'zh_CN' },
        'zh_TW': { name: '中文 (Taiwan)', code: 'zh_TW' }
    };

    languageDefault = 'en';
    localeParameter = window.location.search.match(/locale=([^&#]+)/);
    locale.language = localeParameter && localeParameter[1];
    if (!(locale.language in locale.languages)) {
        languages = window.navigator.languages !== undefined ? window.navigator.languages.slice() : [];
        language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
        languages.push(language);
        languages.push(language.substr(0, 2));
        languages.push(languageDefault);
        for (i = 0; i < languages.length; i++) {
            language = languages[i].replace('-', '_');
            if (language in locale.languages) {
                locale.language = language;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', function (event) {

        if (debugMode) {
            Ext.Loader.setConfig({
                disableCaching: false
            });
        }

        Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'l10n/' + languageDefault + '.json',
            callback: function (options, success, response) {
                window.Strings = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                if (Locale.language !== languageDefault) {
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'l10n/' + Locale.language + '.json',
                        callback: function (options, success, response) {
                            var key, data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                            for (key in data) {
                                if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                    window.Strings[key] = data[key];
                                }
                            }
                            addScriptFile(debugMode ? 'app.js' : 'app.min.js');
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    addScriptFile(debugMode ? 'app.js' : 'app.min.js');
                }
            }
        });

    });

    // Hack for new versions of Android
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') !== -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR') !== -1) {
        var __originalUserAgent = navigator.userAgent;
        navigator.__defineGetter__('userAgent', function () { return __originalUserAgent.replace(/\/OPR[^)]*/g, ''); });
    }

    extjsVersion = '6.2.0';
    olVersion = '5.3.0';
    proj4jsVersion = '2.5.0';

    if (debugMode) {
        addScriptFile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/' + extjsVersion + '/ext-all-debug.js');
        addScriptFile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/' + extjsVersion + '/packages/charts/classic/charts-debug.js');
    } else {
        addScriptFile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/' + extjsVersion + '/ext-all.js');
        addScriptFile('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/' + extjsVersion + '/packages/charts/classic/charts.js');
    }
   addScriptFile('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/' + extjsVersion + '/classic/locale/locale-' + locale.languages[locale.language].code + '.js');

addStyleFile('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/' + extjsVersion + '/classic/theme-aria/resources/theme-aria-all.css');
addScriptFile('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/' + extjsVersion + '/classic/theme-aria/theme-aria.js');

addStyleFile('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/extjs/' + extjsVersion + '/packages/charts/classic/triton/resources/charts-all.css');

    addStyleFile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v' + olVersion + '/css/ol.css');
    addScriptFile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v' + olVersion + '/build/ol.js');



    if (debugMode) {
        addScriptFile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/proj4@' + proj4jsVersion + '/dist/proj4-src.js');
    } else {
        addScriptFile('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/proj4@' + proj4jsVersion + '/dist/proj4.js');
    }

    window.Images = ['arrow', 'default', 'animal', 'bicycle', 'boat', 'bus', 'car', 'crane', 'helicopter', 'motorcycle',
        'offroad', 'person', 'pickup', 'plane', 'ship', 'tractor', 'train', 'tram', 'trolleybus', 'truck', 'van'];

    for (i = 0; i < window.Images.length; i++) {
        addSvgFile('images/' + window.Images[i] + '.svg', window.Images[i] + 'Svg');
    }
})();
```

Comment: If what you want is to make some changes in how traccar looks or functions, you have to download the source code, make your changes there and then recompile the project and install that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to download the source code for the web app first:

https://github.com/traccar/traccar-web

After making the changes, you need generate a minified version of the app that you can upload to your server. There is a script `/tools/minify.sh` in the repo that you can use for that. You will need to have ExtJS and Sencha CMD to run the script. Check following official Traccar documentation for more details:

https://www.traccar.org/build/